# SPARQL DISTINCT gives duplicates in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

The following SPARQL query is giving duplicates in Virtuoso even when the DISTINCT clause is used. You can test the query in the [DBpedia public endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).  Which is the problem with the query?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX dbpedia:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX vrank:<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?person1 ?person1_id ?person2 ?person2_id ?person2_rank
FROM <http://dbpedia.org> 
FROM <http://people.aifb.kit.edu/ath/#DBpedia_PageRank> 
WHERE {
    ?person1 rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person.
    ?person2 rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Person.
    ?person1 ?link ?person2.
    ?person1 dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?person1_id.
    ?person2 dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?person2_id.
    ?person2 vrank:hasRank/vrank:rankValue ?person2_rank.
    FILTER (?person1_id != ?person2_id).
    FILTER (?person1_id = 308)
} ORDER BY DESC(?person2_rank) ASC(?person2_id)
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbpprop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20vrank%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvoc%2Fvrank%23%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson1%20%3Fperson1_id%20%3Fperson2%20%3Fperson2_id%20%3Fperson2_rank%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpeople.aifb.kit.edu%2Fath%2F%23DBpedia_PageRank%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fperson1%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fperson2%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fperson1%20%3Flink%20%3Fperson2.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fperson1%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID%20%3Fperson1_id.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fperson2%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID%20%3Fperson2_id.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%3Fperson2%20vrank%3AhasRank%2Fvrank%3ArankValue%20%3Fperson2_rank.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09FILTER%20%28%3Fperson1_id%20%21%3D%20%3Fperson2_id%29.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09FILTER%20%28%3Fperson1_id%20%3D%20308%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fperson2_rank%29%20ASC%28%3Fperson2_id%29&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The results include rows that appear to be duplicates, e.g.:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle 308 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Democritus  8211 27.281
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle 308 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Democritus  8211 27.281
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle 308 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Heraclitus 13792 26.6914
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle 308 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Heraclitus 13792 26.6914
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle 308 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Parmenides 23575 19.6082
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Aristotle 308 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Parmenides 23575 19.6082
```

Comment: [Also asked on Github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/568). Queries above bring zero solutions on DBpedia today. Can you update your query, and indicate whether you still see the described issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that it appears that there are duplicates in the results. I'm not absolutely sure what the issue with the duplicates is, but I wonder if it might have something do with the inexact equality for floating point numbers.  If, instead of **select**ing the floating point numbers directly, you select their lexical forms with (note the **(str(...) as ?rank)** at the end):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?person1 ?person1_id
  ?person2 ?person2_id
  (str(?person2_rank) as ?rank)
```

I get none of the duplicates.  This might be worth reporting to the Virtuoso folks as a bug.  For what it's worth, if you want floating point values for rank, you can use **xsd:float** as a function to turn that string back into a floating point value, and when I do that, with the **select** like the following, I still get the expected **distinct** results.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  ?person1 ?person1_id
  ?person2 ?person2_id
  (xsd:float(str(?person2_rank)) as ?rank)
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia-owl%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpprop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20vrank%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fvoc%2Fvrank%23%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson1%20%3Fperson1_id%20%3Fperson2%20%3Fperson2_id%20%28xsd%3Afloat%28str%28%3Fperson2_rank%29%29%20as%20%3Frank%29%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E%20%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpeople.aifb.kit.edu%2Fath%2F%23DBpedia_PageRank%3E%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson1%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson2%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson1%20%3Flink%20%3Fperson2.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson1%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID%20%3Fperson1_id.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson2%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID%20%3Fperson2_id.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson2%20vrank%3AhasRank%2Fvrank%3ArankValue%20%3Fperson2_rank.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fperson1_id%20%21%3D%20%3Fperson2_id%29.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fperson1_id%20%3D%20308%29%0D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fperson2_rank%29%20ASC%28%3Fperson2_id%29&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Looks like the formatting of the queries is broken, at least I can see only of parts of them.

Comment: @AKSW It's not broken;  I only posted the `select distinct ... {` part, because that's all I changed.  That's why I led into those parts with, e.g., "you select their lexical forms with".

Comment: Ah, ok - now I got that.

Answer (score 0):

Although this won't help with your dbpedia query, anyone who arrived here via a search on the title who has control of the model and data may want to know that:

virtuoso **double** does not seem to suffer from this SELECT DISTINCT problem that occurs with **float**